# Django Template Round to Nearest Non Zero

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

**Problem:**

Rounding variable size input to variable lengths based on the trailing decimals.

**Description:**

I am building a recipe app for cocktails meaning I want to have some variability with storing measurements in ml at varying lengths.

Let's say I have a recipe consisting of:

- 50ml Gin
- 25ml Lime Juice
- 12.5ml Simple Syrup
- 1.25ml Maraschino Liqueur

*(This is just an example recipe - it's gonna taste like sour piss - don't bother making it)*

This is currently stored in this model:

```
class Ingredients(models.Model):
    SLU = ForeignKey("Spec", on_delete=CASCADE)
    PLU = ForeignKey("Product", on_delete=CASCADE)
    measure = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3, max_digits=5)
```

This means the values in storage are:

- 50.000 Gin
- 25.000 Lemon Juice
- 12.500 Simple Syrup
- 1.250 Maraschino Liqueur

How do I best get these values displayed to the user with no trailing zeroes in the same way as originally displayed above when first showing the recipe?

**Solutions**

Using Django's |floatformat does not solve the problem as it displays as follows:

floatformat:"2": 50.00, 25.00, 12.50, 1.25

floatformat:"-2": 50, 25, 12.50, 1.25

Using a regular Math rounding function in python backend will cause similar results as above unless I make it longer with hard coded options for all 3 possible decimals.

Any good suggestions for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try normalize:

```
{{ measure.normalize }}
```

Comment: The hero we need, not the one we deserve!
Thanks man